# How to not display open button from open file dialogue while downloading file using internet explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, web-applications, download, browser

I have java code through which i set content type of excel and send it to browser. when ever it is downloaded using IE it shows open file dialogue which has OPEN,SAVE,CANCEL button.
I need to avoid this OPEN button and only show SAVE & CANCEL button, how to do this java.
I googled and found info that if we set meta type of contect in IE for download-option as noOPEN then this might be achieved; But i am not getting how to do this using java.

Comment: Show us how did you formed in `Java` code that sends file content to client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in java you can use

```
response.setHeader("X-Download-Options", "noopen");
```

this code for hide open button.

Answer (score 0):

You can either render it inline by setting proper header

```
"content-disposition", "inline;filename=somefile.someExt"
```

or you can make it like attachment

```
"content-disposition", "attachment;filename=somefile.someExt"
```

in which case browser has its own way to prompt user, you **can't** change it [unless your browser provides some sort of setting that your client can set]